# A word to describing "successfully passing a sentry"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or phrase to that describes a soldier successfully passing a sentry and admitted?

Comment: Does it have to be a soldier? Or anyone who is ***cleared*** and ***admitted*** into the restricted area?

Comment: Your question needs clarification... _pass_ is the official language.

Comment: What they said - you ***pass*** or ***clear*** things like checkpoints, customs barriers, inspection, etc.

Comment: @Jim could be anyone. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If our soldier is (for example) just showing his badge and being let into this area, he's cleared, admitted, or allowed to pass. If he's sneaking by, you can also say he's cleared or 'slipped past' the sentry. If he kills/injures the sentry and/or smashes the door blocking access, you can use words such as 'neutralized' or 'broke into.'

Answer (score 1):

***pass***

...from the [General Orders](http://To%20be%20especially%20watchful%20at%20night%20and%20during%20the%20time%20for%20challenging,%20to%20challenge%20all%20persons%20on%20or%20near%20my%20post,%20and%20to%20allow%20no%20one%20to%20pass%20without%20proper%20authority.) (USN)  for a sentry...

> To be especially watchful at night and during the time for challenging, to challenge all persons on or near my post, and to allow no one to ***pass*** without proper authority.